# TabControl padding doesn't work with classic theme

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, themes, padding

Does anyone know why the padding property of TabControl doesn't render with classic theme but works for luna theme?

[image: Classic]

[image: Luna]

The XAML is very basic. I've made the left padding 50 so that the problem is obvious in the screenshots.

```
<!-- Tab control styling -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1" />
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50,5,10,5" />
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3.5" />
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
        </Style>
```

Is there something about classic theme that I'm missing e.g. all padding is ignored?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using one of the tools [ShowMeTheTemplate](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/posts/details/2091) or [Microsoft Expression Blend](http://www.microsoft.com/expression/), you can inspect the control templates that Microsoft has implemented by default for the different themes.

For Windows Classic, the TabControl's control template looks like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
        ...
        <TabPanel .../>
        <Grid ...>
            <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ClassicBorderDecorator ...>
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="2,2,2,2" .../>
            </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ClassicBorderDecorator>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       ...
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

For Luna, it like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Grid ClipToBounds="true" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
        ...
        <TabPanel .../>
        <Border ...>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" .../>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
       ...
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

In Luna, the Padding of the TabControl is bound to the margin of the ContentPresenter; in Windows Classic, the margin is set to 2.

Personally, I think, this is a bug. You might want to create a bug report on http://connect.microsoft.com/ .

As a workaround, you could define your own content template:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" Margin="50,5,10,5"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    ...
<TabControl>
```